# SqlList<DynamicPoco> return dynamic type structure from Stored Procedure

Tags: c#, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

first i would like to thank you for saving Gotham.

I'm calling a Stored Procedure

```
    dbConn.SqlList<UNKNOWN>("exec MY_SP 122254")
```

but i don't know the type of the data returned from the SP, because it can change according to the input parameter values.

**Unfortunately i cannot change the underlying SPROCs and give them a fixed return type.**

Does someone knows a way to map a (let's say) "Generic Object" without knowing its structure?

Thanks...BATMAN!

Comment: OrmLite will only fill out the properties that are returned. You could put all of the possible properties on the class and make them nullable in case they are not returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it by myself even if Batman didn't appear. Next time i'll turn on the BatSignal

I just used the "Massive" Orm (link below) that works sweetly using ExpandoObjects and mapping the data an the types during runtime.

https://github.com/robconery/massive

```
    var massiveModel = new DynamicModel(dbConn.ConnectionString);
    var connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=127.0.0.1;Initial Catalog=TEST;User ID=as;Password=;Application Name=BRUCE_WAYNE");
        connection.Open();
    var massiveConnection = connection;
    var tmp = massiveModel.Query("exec MY_SP 4412 '20131016' ", MassiveConnection).ToList();
```

BTW i'll post another question because my Stored Procedure is returning 2 data-tables. Here's the link: [Servicestack ORMLite/Massive managing multiple DataTables with Expandos / Dynamic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19428025/servicestack-ormlite-massive-managing-multiple-datatables-with-expandos-dynami)

HTH