# Servicestack ORMLite/Massive managing multiple DataTables with Expandos / Dynamic?

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack, expandoobject, dynamicobject, massive

i have a Stored Procedure that returns multiple datatables with dynamic types according to the input  and I cannot modify or split it.

I actually retrieve the data in this way:

```
    var massiveModel = new DynamicModel(dbConn.ConnectionString);
    var connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=127.0.0.1;Initial Catalog=TEST;User ID=as;Password=;Application Name=BRUCE_WAYNE");
        connection.Open();
    var massiveConnection = connection;
    var tmp = massiveModel.Query("exec MY_SP 4412 '20131016' ", MassiveConnection).ToList();
```

How can I handle those multiple datatables while keeping also the capability to dynamically detect the types for each table's column?

Thx anticipately

Comment: Do you have to use ORMLite?

Comment: No, i was just experimenting it coz Servicestack/ORMlite looks really powerful. What do you suggest as alternative?

Comment: Dapper dot net has support for dynamic types and multiple result sets. I'll write up an example for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would give dapper dot net a try.

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=127.0.0.1;Initial Catalog=TEST;User ID=as;Password=;Application Name=BRUCE_WAYNE"))
using (var multi = connection.QueryMultiple("exec MY_SP 4412 '20131016' "))
{
    var resultSetOne = multi.Read().ToList();
    // Do something to determine the type returned...

    var resultSetTwo = multi.Read().ToList();
    // Do something to determine the type returned...
}
```

I haven't tried this exact scenario but it should give you a hint to start from. For further information refer to the [dapper dot net project site](https://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/).